# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while executiing spark RandomForestClassificationExample

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, playframework

I am new in mlib. i wanted to run spark mlib example. I have created new play framework project. and added following dependency :

> name := """EnsembleAI"""
>
> version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
>
> lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
>   scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
>   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(   jdbc,   cache,   ws,
>   "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test,
>   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0",   "org.apache.spark" %%
>   "spark-sql" % "2.3.0",   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.0"
>   )

when i am running following example :

```
package lib

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
// $example on$
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
// $example off$

object RandomForestClassificationExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("RandomForestClassificationExample")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    // $example on$
    // Load and parse the data file.
    val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "sample_libsvm_data.txt")
    // Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
    val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
    val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))

    // Train a RandomForest model.
    // Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.
    val numClasses = 2
    val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
    val numTrees = 3 // Use more in practice.
    val featureSubsetStrategy = "auto" // Let the algorithm choose.
    val impurity = "gini"
    val maxDepth = 4
    val maxBins = 32

    val model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo,
      numTrees, featureSubsetStrategy, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)

    // Evaluate model on test instances and compute test error
    val labelAndPreds = testData.map { point =>
      val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
      (point.label, prediction)
    }
    val testErr = labelAndPreds.filter(r => r._1 != r._2).count.toDouble / testData.count()
    println(s"Test Error = $testErr")
    println(s"Learned classification forest model:\n ${model.toDebugString}")

    // Save and load model
    model.save(sc, "target/tmp/myRandomForestClassificationModel")
    val sameModel = RandomForestModel.load(sc, "target/tmp/myRandomForestClassificationModel")
    // $example off$

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

getting following error :

> 18/03/10 15:01:55 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager:
>   BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.42.97, 34415, None) Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:692)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:821)    at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$.parseLibSVMFile(MLUtils.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$.loadLibSVMFile(MLUtils.scala:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$.loadLibSVMFile(MLUtils.scala:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$.loadLibSVMFile(MLUtils.scala:167)
>     at
>   lib.RandomForestClassificationExample$.main(RandomForestClassificationExample.scala:16)
>     at
>   lib.RandomForestClassificationExample.main(RandomForestClassificationExample.scala)
>   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Incompatible Jackson version: 2.7.8   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala)
>     ... 8 more

and here is the [sample_libsvm_data.txt](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt).

---

### Note : above example taken from spark example only.

---

**Please guide me where i am wrong .**

Comment: Why do you want to use Play and Spark in the same project? Since _"I am new in mlib. i wanted to run spark mlib example." why don't you start with a standalone Spark MLlib app first? I'm pretty sure you'd have avoided the _"Incompatible Jackson version"_ issue.

Comment: I have tried in standalone mode. now i am trying to resolve some real life problems.

Comment: In real life project that solves real life problems I'd separate a web component from a Spark application as they have different lifecycles with web requests being short-lived whereas Spark jobs often longer.